# Why does 「もう待てないよ！」 mean "I can't wait any longer"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, expressions, conjugations

I've just learnt that the expression 「もう待てないよ！」 has similar meaning in English as "I can't wait any longer", but how to interpret 「待てない」 from a grammar point?

Shouldn't the "te-form" of 「待つ」 be 「待って」like in 「待っててね！」?

And why 「待ってない」 doesn't mean something like "I'm not waiting (right now)", since it's the "nai-form" of 「待ってる」.

Here're some websites I've referred to:

https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/11115/

https://ameblo.jp/aki-aki-tokachan/entry-11925700002.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

待って is indeed the te-form, but 待て is not. It is the potential form. Remember that the final う sound becomes an え sound for the potential form of godan verbs? I guess this verb is a little more confusing than usual because つ becomes て (there not being a tse sound).

So the positive potential form of the verb is now 待てる. This conjugates like a normal ichidan verb so the negative form becomes 待てない as seen in your example.

Comment: Strictly speaking, 待て with nothing else attached would be the command form, with no relation to potential. But as you noted later, the 待てない comes from 待てる

Comment: @Leebo Good point. I guess that wasn't as clear as it should be. Do you think it's worth an edit? I'm thinking your comment is probably sufficient.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, 待て could also be the potential form on its own, if it was functioning as the conjunction-type masu-stem. So yeah, it's not wrong, and anyone could just look at the comments if they had the same thought.

Answer (score 3):

待っていない　not waiting
待てない　not be able to wait